# JPQL: result if Map<> contains specific or doesn't contain at all

Tags: java, mysql, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to compile a query that would return an entity that contains Map<> in it. The restriction is that this map should either contain particular key-value pair or this key does not need to be present at all.

what I have:

```
SELECT M FROM Metadata M left outer JOIN M.additionals A 
WHERE M.UUID = :uuid
AND M.versionVed = :versionVed 
AND 
KEY(A) = '" + Vedantas.SOFT_DEL + "' 
AND VALUE(A) <> 'true'
```

this is the first part of requirement, so it lacks logic for returning result if that key is not present at all.

Is there some elegant way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
"SELECT M FROM Metadata M where m.id not in (
   select subMetadata.id from Metadata subMetadata JOIN M.additionals A where 
       KEY(A) = :key AND VALUE(A) <> :value)"
```

The subquery returns IDs with the key with values that don't match the one you are looking for, allowing them to be filtered from the main query.